# How to understand 'for' loops in Bash?

Tags: bash, numbers, counter, counting

My goal here is to enter for example 5 or 3 in read field and get needed output.

If I will enter 5 it will show as following:

```
Enter num: 5 <----
one
two
three
four
five
```

and if I will enter 3 it will show:

```
Enter num: 3 <----
one
two
three
```

I can't figure out what I miss here.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter num:"

read num

if [[ $num = 5 ]]; then
count=5
fi

if [[ $num = 10 ]]; then
count=10
fi

steps=( [1]=step_one [2]=step_two [3]=step_three [4]=step_four [5]=step_five [6]=step_six [7]=step_seven [8]=step_eight [9]=step_nine [10]=step_ten )
max=${1:-$count}

step_one()   { echo "one"; }
step_two()   { echo "two"; }
step_three() { echo "three"; }
step_four()  { echo "four"; }
step_five()  { echo "five"; }
step_six()   { echo "six"; }
step_seven()   { echo "seven"; }
step_eight() { echo "eight"; }
step_nine()  { echo "nine"; }
step_ten()  { echo "ten"; }



for ((i=1; i<=max; i++)); do
          "${steps[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Change `i<=max` to `i<=num`

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks for help here! it works perfectly, but it prints the number related to ```num``` before the list

Comment: Those other variables don't seem needed at all.

Comment: please update the question to include the (wrong) output generated by your script when entering `5` or `10`

Comment: @markp-fuso, sorry, my bad! Done :)

Comment: Please try to use question titles that contain a useful summary of the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help guys! now all works perfectly!!!

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter num:"

read num

steps=( [1]=step_one [2]=step_two [3]=step_three [4]=step_four [5]=step_five [6]=step_six [7]=step_seven [8]=step_eight [9]=step_nine [10]=step_ten )

step_one()   { echo "one"; }
step_two()   { echo "two"; }
step_three() { echo "three"; }
step_four()  { echo "four"; }
step_five()  { echo "five"; }
step_six()   { echo "six"; }
step_seven()   { echo "seven"; }
step_eight() { echo "eight"; }
step_nine()  { echo "nine"; }
step_ten()  { echo "ten"; }

for ((i=1; i<=num; i++)); do
          "${steps[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: You're reading `num`, but going up to `max`. Maybe you want `read max` instead of `read num`? BTW, you can `read -p "Echo num:" max` to not need a separate `echo` line to write the prompt (this also puts the prompt on stderr, which stops it from interfering with redirection of stdout).

Comment: Glad to hear! Maybe [edit] the answer to incorporate the fix? We want other people to be able to learn from the problem and its solution.